# Why are all of my files being deleted at the end of the installation?

Tags: wix

My company uses Wix Toolset to create an installation package for one of our applications.  As part of an upgrade, we changed the names of some executables and dlls.

When I attempt to install the new version on a machine with the old version (something that had worked flawlessly beforehand), everything works fine until the very end of the installation, when all of the files in the installation directory are unceremoniously deleted.

What setting is causing this?  If this has happened to you, what dumb thing did you do to cause it and what restored balance to the world?

Thanks.

Comment: My guess is you have all new component GUIDs so the old installer when uninstalling checks the reference count on its components and sees they are all at 1 (itself) so it just deletes them. You should do an upgrade with logging on "msiexec /i installer.msi /l*v log.txt" and post the log here.

Comment: Alternatively, you can schedule RemoveExistingProducts at AfterInstallInitialize and your problems should go away. (But this doesn't fix the underlying issue that you are seeing)

Comment: Your old install could also have a `<util:RemoveFolderEx>` somewhere in it which is deleting everything.